# Error Hardware Accelerated VT-x - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

VT-x is active in bios, my system is x64. How can I do to install intelhaxm-android.exe? The error is this: s18.postimg.org/kgtu90rqx/Immagine.png

Comment: When you solve your own question, the best thing to do is post the solution as an answer to the question, and accept it by clicking the check mark.  Otherwise the question stays marked as "unanswered"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: I solved by installing the Android SDK 4.0.3 !!